# How is Google Analytics building it's tracking pixel request?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I'm trying to create the smallest request possible that contains some tracking data. The headers are responsible for about half of the request size right now and I'm trying to reduce them.

I noticed that the Google Analytics tracking pixel (www.google-analytics.com/collect) has no request headers except for Referer and User-Agent.

I've tried embedding an image and making an XMLHttpRequest, but both add extra headers to the request. I also tried using the "setRequestHeader" with "null" as the second parameter, but this just makes the header "null" instead of removing it.

How is Google generating such a small request?

Edit: It looks like Google Analytics is only missing the headers in Chrome. I'm guessing that they delete the headers in the browser rather than having the ability to do it in javascript.

Comment: I assume the pixel also makes use of tracking cookies being sent to google analytics which allows them to identify a user. Not sure why that's filtered in Chrome. Haven't checked the behavior yet but maybe your browser is blocking tracking cookies via an extension